# Problem printing out array using putchar function. Getting a punch of symbols as output

Tags: arrays, c, loops, pointers, putchar

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_rev(char *s);

int main(void)
{
    char *str;
    str = "I do not fear computers. I fear the lack of them - Isaac Asimov";
    print_rev(str);
    return (0);
}

// read array and print it out backwards char by char.
void print_rev(char *s)
{
    int arrLength;

    arrLength = 0;

    // capture length of array
    while (*s != '\0') {
        arrLength++;
        s++;
    }

    arrLength--;

    // print array backwards
    for (; arrLength >= 0; arrLength--) {
        putchar(s[arrLength]);
    }

    putchar('\n');
}
```

This is my code. When I run it, all I can do is get it to print out this output:
[picture of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNVh4.png)

I tried researching why this happens but I can't find any videos where people use `putchar` and not `printf`. Much help appreciated.

The point of my code is to take the string and reverse it using `putchar`.
I cannot use the function `strlen()`.

**Expected output:**

```
vomisA caasI - meht fo kcal eht raef I .sretupmoc raef ton od I
```

Comment: `s++;` moves the pointer you are using to index. You need to make a copy or restore it to the original position after your loop checking the length. You could also use `while (s[arrLength] != '\0')` so you don't modify it.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, or `strlen()`

Comment: Please indent your code properly. This was very confusing.

Comment: @CraigEstey Changed it a little bit to remove all scrolling

Comment: @klutt It takes a village [to raise a child] ...

Answer (score 2):

In `print_rev()`, during your first pass where you reinvent the `strlen()` wheel, you also increment `s` to point to the terminating NUL character.

In the last loop, you are reusing `s` as if it hadn't changed: `s[arrLength]` obviously point outside of your string since `s` points to the end of it.

Solution: change

```
for (; arrLength >= 0; arrLength--) {
    putchar(s[arrLength]);
}
```

to

```
for (; arrLength >= 0; arrLength--) {
    s--;
    putchar(*s);
}
```

Comment: "during your first pass when you reinvented the strlen wheel" HAHHAHAHA! Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: My pleasure. Feel free to use `strlen()` instead :-)